# Review sessions from timestamp column with start/stop event with duplicate start/stop records

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have following case change records:

| id | case_id | state | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | REVIEW_NEEDED | 2021-03-30 15:11:58.015907000 |
| 2 | 100 | REVIEW_NEEDED | 2021-04-01 13:08:17.945926000 |
| 3 | 100 | REVIEW | 2021-04-07 06:20:48.873865000 |
| 4 | 100 | WAITING | 2021-04-07 06:32:47.159664000 |
| 5 | 100 | REVIEW_NEEDED | 2021-04-09 06:32:51.132127000 |
| 6 | 100 | REVIEW | 2021-04-12 04:39:36.426467000 |
| 7 | 100 | REVIEW | 2021-04-12 04:40:36.000000000 |
| 8 | 100 | CLOSED | 2021-04-12 04:40:43.133736000 |
| 9 | 101 | REVIEW_NEEDED | 2021-03-30 20:37:58.015907000 |
| 10 | 101 | REVIEW | 2021-04-04 13:08:17.945926000 |
| 11 | 101 | CLOSED | 2021-04-06 06:20:48.873865000 |
| 12 | 101 | CLOSED | 2021-04-06 06:20:50.000000000 |

I'd like to report sessions out of these like following:

| open_id | close_id | case_id | waiting_time_start | handling_time_start | handling_time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 100 | 2021-03-30 15:11:58.015907000 | 2021-04-07 06:20:48.873865000 | 2021-04-07 06:32:47.159664000 |
| 5 | 8 | 100 | 2021-04-09 06:32:51.132127000 | 2021-04-12 04:39:36.426467000 | 2021-04-12 04:40:43.133736000 |
| 9 | 11 | 101 | 2021-03-30 20:37:58.015907000 | 2021-04-04 13:08:17.945926000 | 2021-04-06 06:20:48.873865000 |

*Waiting_time_start*: when state = REVIEW_NEEDED

*Handling_time_start*: when state = REVIEW

*Handling_time_end*: when state = WAITING or CLOSED

My current solution is to rank the *Waiting_time_start*, *Handling_time_start* and *Handling_time_end* for each case and then join these events on rank, but this is not perfect as there's duplicate records, so number of start/stop events can differ for a case.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  Start by adding a grouping based on the count of "waiting" and "closed" -- but only when they change values:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when (state <> next_state or next_state is null) and
                     state in ('WAITING', 'CLOSED')
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (partition by caseid order by time_created desc) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lead(state) over (partition by caseid order by time_created) as next_state
      from t
     ) t
```

Then, you can just aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when (state <> next_state or next_state is null) and
                           state in ('WAITING', 'CLOSED')
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by caseid order by time_created desc) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(state) over (partition by caseid order by time_created) as next_state
            from t
           ) t
     )
select caseid, min(id), max(id),
       min(case when status = 'REVIEW_NEEDED' then time_created end),
       min(case when status = 'REVIEW' then time_created end),
       max(time_created)
from cte
group by grouping, caseid;
```

Comment: Thank you, works well. (the two code snippets should be swapped though)